# "Run manage.py task" and .env file environment variables

Tags: django, pycharm

In PyCharm one can set environment variables in the "Run/Debug" configurations with the EnvFile plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile). That works for the configuration e.g. the default Django development server.

However, it doesn't work with the **Tools->Run manage.py Task** menu. I know that I can set environment variables in the PyCharm Django settings (Preferences -> Language and Frameworks -> Django) but there I can't use an env file, but only specify each environment variable manually. Is there a convenient way how my "Run manage.py Task" always have the same settings as in the Run configuration?

I am using PyCharm 2020.3.3 (Professional Edition), Build #PY-203.7148.72.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that plug in can work with the section in settings under Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Console -> Django Console

I believe when manually set there in the Environment variables, that's where the manage tool picks up the vars.

EDIT:
ah. sorry. I think you've stated that already. It is a real shame there isn't an easy way to set that up. Struggle with it on each new project. I've switched back to using an env file and sourcing it as part of my activate virtual environment alias and doing all the manage stuff in the shell.